# How to know it's the first time Pivot Item got focus?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to load some data, but on the first time user is watching the `PivotItem`. How to see it's the first time user is on a special item?
...

I can use `GotFocus` event and use a variable like `IsLoaded = false`, but it doesn't look nice.

```
<phone:PivotItem GotFocus="Item_GotFocus">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name each `PivotItem` such as `<phone:PivotItem x:Name="Pivot1"/>`, then use `Pivot`'s `SelectionChanged`

```
private void MyPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if(e.AddedItems.Contains(Pivot1))
        //Do stuff here
}
```

In order to check to see if they've been there before, you can create a `List<PivotItem>` and add the ones that have been seen to it.

```
private List<PivotItem> _seenPivots;

// The page constructor
public MyPage()
{
    //Regular Page initialization
    _seenPivots = new List<PivotItem>();
}
```

Then change the `SelectionChanged` handler to:

```
private void MyPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if(e.AddedItems.Contains(Pivot1))
    {
        if(_seenPivots.Contains(Pivot1))
            return;

        _seenPivots.Add(Pivot1);
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Edit: Added section for checking for first time.

Comment: thanks @NateDiamond. I checked and it worked but still I need a variable to check if it is the first time the item is activated

Comment: Edited to add a check for that

Answer (score 0):

Try using LoadingPivotItem handler

code snippet

**XAML**

```
<controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" x:Name="MyPivotControl" LoadingPivotItem="Pivot_LoadingPivotItem">
```

**C#**

```
 private void Pivot_LoadingPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (MyPivotControl.SelectedIndex)
        { 
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("First pivot page is actived");
                break;
            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show("Second pivot page is actived");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Oscar, it's better than my solution, but still I need a variable to see if it is the first time that the item is activated.